# Missing Server and User in Credentials .Host 'TS-TAYYIBAH-PC.techno-soft.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having error in DB first approach , when I try to choose my data connection it shows the following exception:
    "Missing Server and User in Credentials ".
And when I enter all credentials(including server name ,username,password,database port ,user id) in "Connection Properties" it throws exception:
    "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

here are the connection strings I have in my web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionString" value="server=10.10.10.35;user id=tls_dev;password=tls_dev;persistsecurityinfo=True;port=3306;database=tls_dev" />
</appSettings>



<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ExamBuilder.csdl|res://*/Models.ExamBuilder.ssdl|res://*/Models.ExamBuilder.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=10.10.10.35;user id=tls_dev;password=tls_dev;persistsecurityinfo=True;port=3306;database=tls_dev&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ExamBuilder.csdl|res://*/Models.ExamBuilder.ssdl|res://*/Models.ExamBuilder.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=10.10.10.35;user id=tls_dev;password=tls_dev;database=tls_dev;persistsecurityinfo=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And I have included "ConnectionString" in Global.asax like: 
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(new MySqlStorage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]));

Comment: I just installed the following versions on my pc ,and uninstalled the previous versions  

 

The pakages I had installed are:  
    1)MySql Connector Net 6.9.9  
    2)MySql for Visual STudio 1.2.7

Comment: This still did not resolved my error , I deleted the cross signed connection in my server explorer,and created new connection and changed connection string in web.config .May it helps others

Comment: You can also check this :

Comment: http://tayyibahalauddin.over-blog.com/2018/09/severity-code-description-project-file-line-suppression-state-error-mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlproviderservices-mysql.data.entity-v